# How to return a JSONObject on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a web service that is calling another web service:

```
String restServiceUrl = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?start" + start + "&limit=" + limit + "&sort=" + sort;
String coinmarketcapJSONString = new RestTemplate().getForObject(restServiceUrl, String.class);
JSONObject coinmarketcapJSONObject = new JSONObject(coinmarketcapJSONString).getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray coinmarketcapJSONArray = coinmarketcapJSONObject.names();
```

My *coinmarketcapJSONObject* looks like this:

```
{"1":{"symbol":"BTC","circulating_supply":1.7300962E7,"last_updated":1538495424,"total_supply":1.7300962E7,"name":"Bitcoin","max_supply":2.1E7,"rank":1,"id":1,"website_slug":"bitcoin","quotes":{"USD":{"percent_change_1h":-0.1,"market_cap":1.13449548429E11,"percent_change_24h":-0.12,"price":6557.41272818,"volume_24h":3.85360400868166E9,"percent_change_7d":2.1}}},"1027":{"symbol":"ETH","circulating_supply":1.02322624E8,"last_updated":1538495440,"total_supply":1.02322624E8,"name":"Ethereum","max_supply":null,"rank":2,"id":1027,"website_slug":"ethereum","quotes":{"USD":{"percent_change_1h":-0.21,"market_cap":2.3260421917E10,"percent_change_24h":-0.19,"price":227.32432918,"volume_24h":1.49265685549155E9,"percent_change_7d":7.69}}}}
```

I want to return it like that:

```
return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(coinmarketcapJSONObject, HttpStatus.OK);
```

But when I do that I keep stucked with an error:

> "No converter found for return value of type: class
>   org.json.JSONArray"

[image]

I looked on the web that I must install Jackson dependencies. I installed them but nothing changed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: return new ResponseEntity<String>(coinmarketcapJSONObject.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: @RobertoManfreda, Thank you it's not bad but I want to return a true JSON object, not a string

Comment: Encapsulate your coinmarketcapJSONString in a CustomClass and write getter and setter, maybe tis is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return it as String.

`return new ResponseEntity<String>(coinmarketcapJSONObject.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: Thank you it's not bad but I want to return a true JSON object, not a string

Comment: JSON is a String. But what is the reason behind returning TRUE JSON object? You could even return `List` which Spring would automatically convert to JSON array. But again, why not String?

Comment: The way it looks on Postman is weird. I hope it can be parsed by the front end.

Comment: After I added produces="application/json" to @RequestMapping it solved the display issue, thanks!!